# unable to store special characters from mysql into a json file - Python

Tags: python, mysql, json

I have a script to fetch data from a mysql table. One of the columns within the table contains spanish characters like á,é,etc,etc and before executing main query, it is set the utf8 output.

After executing the queries, the data that contains the mentioned special characters is fine and I can print out without seeing anything different. However, my problem is when I create a json file as the output and save the file, the resulting data is encoded as unicode and not as spanish text. I also have tried decoding the output from mysql and encoding when the json file is saved but I still see those special characters in unicode.

I know before using special characters it is necessary to decode->unicode and finally if i want to save the data, it has to be encoded. However, that is not working out. You can see a short version of my python script.

```
import json
import collections
#Database connection
...
#getting the cursor
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute(' SET NAMES utf8' )
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM eqs ORDER BY localdate DESC, localtime DESC')
....
master_object= collections.OrderedDict()
for row in rows:
    #adding data within the master_object
j=json.dumps(master_object) # <- Here, I tried enconding the data (master_object,enconding='utf-8') and with in the for loop i decode the string
fo=open('output.json','w')
fo.write(j)
fo.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be creating an ASCII-encoded json file with json-encoded strings, which is the typical use case for storing JSON files.

I think you want a UTF-8 encoded json file. To do that, set `ensure_ascii=False` in your json-encoding step, so that the utf8-encoded strings are passed straight through to the file.

Something like this might work for you.

```
import json
master_objects = {
    "tomorrow" : "ma\xc3\xb1ana" # UTF-8 encoding, just like what comes from db
}

print master_objects["tomorrow"] # Should print man~ana, only prettier

with open("output.json", "wt") as output_file:
    json.dump(master_objects, output_file, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; that did the trick for saving the data as I want.

Comment: great! This worked like a charm. Anybody knows why this works and why setting  encoding='utf8' doesn't? for example in: with open(f'./hierarchy/{website}_api_category_tree.json', 'w', encoding='utf8')